# After Xcode distributes to app store... where is the .app and .dSYM?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, app-store, app-store-connect

I just uploaded a binary to the app store, using Xcode's Product -> Archive, and then Distribute (when the window pops up).

In the old days, there would be a .app file and a .dSYM file for the project in the Products folder, upon which I could right-click, then "Show in Finder", and make a copy of what I found there for backup (as well as a zip of the project), or in case I ever need to symbolicate any App Crash Reports.

Now, the only .app file there is from much earlier, not the time that the build was pushed to the app store, and there is no .dSYM file.

Do I still need them? Are they now elsewhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Xcode 4.0 and later, when you build and archive,  the products of your target and their dSYM file will be all archived. The archives can used to symbolicate crash logs.

select the archive, and [show package contents], you can see the dSYMs and app are there.

Comment: Thanks, found it. To be clear for other readers, that's under Window -> Organizer -> Archives tab, right click the archive and select 'Show in Finder'.